# Odoo segregate Point of Sale categories for multi-company use

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am self-hosting Odoo 12 Community Edition (Configuring before uploading my Subscription Key). I am attempting to configure Point of Sales for two different companies, I noticed I can set the starting POS category for each company but what I'm trying to accomplish is to seperate the categories and products to only be available in their respective Points of Sale. I'm new to Odoo so I am not sure if this would have unintended consequences due to table relationships.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: So as far as i understand your question, you want to do something like, for all your POS, you want to set different categories and products for different companies (POS) and each pos not reflect another pos's categories or products. Is it so ?

Comment: @KevalMehta - I am too facing the same issue, products is working fine, only the products related to particular company are listed but all POS product categories are getting displayed under all the companies. I am using odoo 13 community.

Comment: @Aks1357 What exactly you are facing issue here ?

Comment: @KevalMehta - the categories created in one company are visible in other companies also, don't want any reference or actionable of other company categories. In products we have a option to select the company in which the product belongs to.